# How to get the mean of the tertiles for each column in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

I am trying to get the Long Term Average for the tertiles of all the variables in my dataframe.
Basically, I want the mean value for the three tertiles of each variable. Hereunder, an example for the second tertile.

Data structure:

```
DOY   city     P        BP       prune   Tmax
100 Bechem 1.283868 0.001742587  1.00 29.07214
123 Bechem 0.000000 0.002593004  0.02 30.42596
345 Bechem 0.000000 0.421595923  0.02 30.03821
100 Bechem 1.283868 0.001742587  1.00 29.07214
123 Bechem 0.000000 0.002593004  0.02 30.42596
345 Bechem 0.000000 0.393785818  0.02 29.03066
100 Bechem 1.283868 0.001742587  1.00 29.07214
123 Bechem 0.000000 0.002593004  0.02 30.42596
345 Bechem 0.000000 0.174428952  0.02 32.00171
100 Bechem 1.283868 0.001742587  1.00 29.07214
```

What I do now is:

```
Fun_tertile_mean <- function(x,i){
  quantile<-quantile(x, c(0:3/3))
  datum <- mean(x[x<= quantile[i] & x>quantile[i-1]],na.rm = TRUE)
  return(datum)
}

Data_General_2tertile <- Data_General[Data_General$yr_prjctd %in% c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015),] %>%
    group_by(city) %>% 
      group_by(DOY) %>%
        select_if(is.numeric) %>%
          summarise_all(function(x) Fun_tertile_mean(x,3))
```

I obtain a dataframe full of NaN and some values and I do not understand if there is something wrong in the function I defined, in the interaction between group_by() and summarise_all().

Any tip or help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to SO!

I believe the problem is that you are getting tertile limits that are equal. If that is the case, you will get a `NaN` as a result of the mean. Here is an example with `iris`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
 
data("iris")
 
 Fun_tertile_mean <- function(x, i) {
+   quantile <- quantile(x, c(0:3 / 3))
+   datum <- mean(x[x <= quantile[i] & x > quantile[i - 1]], na.rm = TRUE)
+   return(datum)
+ }
 
 iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
+   select_if(is.numeric) %>%
+   summarise_all(function(x) Fun_tertile_mean(x, 3))

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 setosa             5.05        3.42         1.5       NaN   
2 versicolor         5.97        2.85         4.38        1.4 
3 virginica          6.54        2.99         5.54        2.05
 
quantile(iris[iris$Species == "setosa", "Petal.Width"], c(0:3 / 3))
       0% 33.33333% 66.66667%      100% 
      0.1       0.2       0.2       0.6
```

One solution could be using `ifelse`, and taking the value instead of the mean:

```
Fun_tertile_mean <- function(x, i) {
+   quantile <- quantile(x, c(0:3 / 3), digits = 10)
+   datum <- ifelse(quantile[i] == quantile[i - 1], quantile[i], mean(x[x <= quantile[i] & x > quantile[i - 1]], na.rm = TRUE))
+   return(datum)
+ }
 
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
+   select_if(is.numeric) %>%
+   summarise_all(function(x) Fun_tertile_mean(x, 3))

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 setosa             5.05        3.42         1.5         0.2 
2 versicolor         5.97        2.85         4.38        1.4 
3 virginica          6.54        2.99         5.54        2.05
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much @Santiago Capobianco. Now the code is working! I still wonder why it poses a problem if the values are equal to a quantile... they should be included in one of the ranges... Anyway, thanks a lot!